# How to link dropdown change event to PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, mysqli

**Scenario**

I have the following HTML code for the drop down menu

```html
<div class="form-group col-sm-2">
  <label>Machine</label><br>
  <select class="combobox form-control col-sm-2" name="machineNumber">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select><br>
  <label id="machineSer">Machine Serial Number: <?php echo $serialNumberRemarks; ?></label>
</div>
```

**What I need**

When there is a change in the combobox, I need to run the following php function that runs a query and fetch data to display an item accordingly to the label with id `machineSer`. My php function as follows

```
<?php
    function labelVal(){
        if(isset($_POST['machineNumber'])){
            $machineName = $_POST['machineNumber'];

            $query = "SELECT machineSerialRemarks FROM machinenames WHERE machineName = '$machineName'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $serialNumberRemarks = $row['machineSerialRemarks'];
            return $serialNumberRemarks;
        }
    }
?>
```

Does anyone knows how to do it? I know this has something to do with Javascript and probably Ajax. I look through some of the Ajax but I don't understand how it works. Is there any way to do this without using Javascript? If that is not possible, how can I link this two with Javascript and Ajax?

Comment: please read about SQL injections - https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=SQL+injections&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: @BookOfZeus Thanks for the reminder. However, I am using this just to do some internal development only which will not use in public domains. So security is not a big issue for this case

Comment: SQL Injections is always a good practice no matter what IMO

Comment: But for this case, there is no text input fields. Only a drop down box and a button. So I worry less about it

Comment: Doesn't matter. a) Since you'll be using AJAX to make a request to a server, and requests can be faked, your server can receive any input. b) Always practice safety even when not important, so that when it is important it will be second nature and there's no chance of accidents. c) Estimating safety is not safe. In this case, your estimate was wrong. Be safe always, so even when you're wrong, you're safe.

Comment: @Amadan Alright. Will use some sql injection prevention techniques. But could you please tell me how to link this two using Ajax? Also just curious, is there any other way other than Ajax?

Comment: Yes, websockets. That's even more advanced, though.

Comment: Yes you will need to use ajax for this task. You can add an onchange listener to the select element e.g onchange="selectMachineNumber ()" then create a javascript function called selectMachineNumber which makes the ajax request to a php file (containing your php script). Echo back a json encoded response. Then insert the response to your html where desired.

Comment: Hey Anu and also everyone who commented here about SQL injection. I updated my answer (See "Edit 2-Making the PHP code more secure") showing how to use PDO with prepared statements to make accessing the database more secure. Also If anyone has any thoughts on this I'd welcome your opinion. I'm always security conscious so have done a bit of research over the years to try make my code for accessing the database as secure as I can. Let me know if there is anything extra you can think of that could be added for security. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use AJAX for this task. You can use either jQuery ajax or vanilla JavaScript ajax.

I have created a full working example using vanilla JavaScript which I have tested and it works fine.

Here's the changes I made:

1. I added an `onchange` listener to the select element in the HTML e.g `onchange="selectMachineNumber()"`
2. I created a javascript function called `selectMachineNumber` which will be executed everytime the select menu is changed. Within this function we make the ajax request to a php file called machine_number_processing.php (containing your php script).
3. I echo back a json encoded response containing the `serialNumberRemarks` variable.
4. Then I inserted the `serialNumberRemarks` to your html in a span tag (within your label). The span tag has an id of: `machine-serial-number`.

## index.html (or whatever the name of your HTML page is)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<script>
//declare a global xmlhttp variable 
var xmlhttp;

function createXHR(){
  //This function sets up the XMLHttpRequest
  try{
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }catch(e){
    //to support older browsers
    try{
      return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }catch(e){
      return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
  }
}

function selectMachineNumber(selectElement){
   //this function will be called when there is a change in the machineNumber select menu
   //check the value selected in the console as follows:
   console.log(selectElement.value);
   var machineNumber = selectElement.value;
   //do ajax request
   xmlhttp = createXHR();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = ajaxCallback; //name of our callback function here
   //Ive called the php file machine_number_processing.php but you can call it whatever you like.
   xmlhttp.open("POST", "machine_number_processing.php" ,true);
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   //send our variables with the request
   xmlhttp.send("machineNumber=" + machineNumber);
}

function ajaxCallback(){
   //this function will be executed once the ajax request is completed
   if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
      //The ajax request was successful.
      //we can now get the response text using xmlhttp.responseText. 
      //This will be whatever was echoed in the php file
      //we also need to parse this as JSON because we used json_encode on the PHP array we sent back 
      var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      console.log(data.machineNumber); 
      console.log(data.serialNumberRemarks);
      //insert the serialNumberRemarks to the span tag with id="machine-serial-number"
      document.getElementById("machine-serial-number").innerText = data.serialNumberRemarks;

   }
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
  <label>Machine</label><br>
  <select class="combobox form-control col-sm-2" name="machineNumber" id="machineNumber" onchange="selectMachineNumber(this)">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select><br>
  <label id="machineSer">Machine Serial Number: <span id="machine-serial-number"></span></label>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

## machine_number_processing.php

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['machineNumber'])){
    $machineName = $_POST['machineNumber'];

    $query = "SELECT machineSerialRemarks FROM machinenames WHERE machineName = '$machineName'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $serialNumberRemarks = $row['machineSerialRemarks'];

    //create a PHP array to store the data we will send back to the client side
    $responseData = array(); 
    //store the machineNumber that was submitted into a variable in order to test the ajax request
    //without performing the SQL query.
    $responseData['machineNumber'] = $_POST['machineNumber']; 

    //store the $serialNumberRemarks variable into our response array
    $responseData['serialNumberRemarks'] = $serialNumberRemarks;
    echo json_encode($responseData); //echo the response data back to the client
  }
?>
```

Note: As you know (as people have said in the comments) you'll need to look into making your SQL code more secure but for demonstration purposes I have left your PHP code as it is.

Hope this helps :)

## Edit

**If you just want to test** that the ajax request is working (without doing the SQL query) then change your php file to the following

## machine_number_processing.php

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['machineNumber'])){
    $machineName = $_POST['machineNumber'];
    //create a PHP array to store the data we will send back to the client side
    $responseData = array(); 
    //store the machineNumber that was submitted into a variable in order to test the ajax request
    //without performing the SQL query.
    $responseData['machineNumber'] = $_POST['machineNumber']; 

    echo json_encode($responseData); //echo the response data back to the client
  }
?>
```

And in the `ajaxCallback` function **comment out these two lines**:

```
 console.log(data.serialNumberRemarks);
 document.getElementById("machine-serial-number").innerText = data.serialNumberRemarks;
```

You can check the response you get under the Network tab in developer tools as follows:

[image: response]

## Edit 2-Making the PHP code more secure

I wanted to show an example of how to use the **PHP Data Objects (PDO)** extension in your project. 
This is an interface for accessing databases in PHP.

It has **prepared statements**, which helps make the processing more secure (i.e **helps to prevent against SQL injection**).

Here's a working example of how you can incorporate it to your code (instead of using mysqli)

Your file where you set up the connection would be something like as follows:

**connect.php**

```
<?php
  //Define our connection variables. (really these credentials should be in a file stored in a private folder on the server but i'll them here for simplicity.)
  //set the character set for more security. (I will use utf8mb4. This is a good idea if you want to store emojis. YOu can just use utf8 though.
  define("HOSTDBNAME", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=machine_app;charset=utf8mb4");     
  define("USER", "root");    
  define("PASSWORD", ""); 

  //initiate a PDO connection
  $pdoConnection = new PDO(HOSTDBNAME, USER, PASSWORD);
  $pdoConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
  $pdoConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  //set the character set for more security. set it to utf8mb4 so we can store emojis. you can just use utf8 if you like.
  $pdoConnection->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");

?>
```

Create a file called phpfunctions.php to hold a `getSerialNumberRemarks()` function which makes the query to the database to get `$serialNumberRemarks`

**phpfunctions.php**

```
<?php
  function getSerialNumberRemarks($machineName, $pdoConnection){
    /*
     * This is a function to access the machinenames table using PDO with prepared statements and named parameters.
     * I have included extra comments (for learning purposes) with appropriate information taken
     * from the documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php
     */
    $serialNumberRemarks = ""; 
    try{
      //We create our $query with our named (:name) parameter markers 
      //These parameters will be substituted with real values when the statement is executed.
      //Use these parameters to bind any user-input, (N.B do not include the user-input directly in the query).    
      $query ="SELECT machineSerialRemarks FROM machinenames WHERE machineName = :machineName";

      //We now use the PDO::prepare() method on the query.
      //Note: calling PDO::prepare() and PDOStatement::execute() helps to prevent SQL injection attacks by eliminating the need 
      //to manually quote and escape the parameters.    
      $statement = $pdoConnection->prepare($query);

      //We now bind our user-input values.
      //If the user-input is an INT value then use PDO::PARAM_INT, if it is a string then use PDO::PARAM_STR.
      //$machineName will be an INT so bind the value as follows.
      $statement->bindValue(':machineName', $machineName, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
      $statement->execute();
      $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      while($row = $statement->fetch()){
        $serialNumberRemarks = $row['machineSerialRemarks'];
      }
      return $serialNumberRemarks;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
      throw new Exception($e);
    }   
  }
?>
```

The following is the file the AJAX request is going to. We need to include the connect.php file and the phpfunctions.php file.

**machine_number_processing.php**

```
<?php
  require("connect.php"); //this file contains our PDO connection configuration
  require("phpfunctions.php"); //this file contains the getSerialNumberRemarks(); function

  if(isset($_POST['machineNumber'])){
    //store $_POST['machineNumber'] into a local variable
    $machineName = $_POST['machineNumber'];

    //checks should be done here to check the input is valid i.e it's a valid length, its valid encoding.
    //You should also filter the input. 
    //This can be done with PHP methods such as trim(), htmlspecialchars(), strip_tags(), stripslashes() 
    //and other methods depending on the type of input.
    //In this demonstration I will perform minimal sanitization of the input. 
    //Note: if its a string use FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING instead
    $machineName = filter_var($machineName, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    //create a PHP array to store the data we will send back to the client side
    $responseData = array(); 

    //call the getSerialNumberRemarks() function and store the serialNumberRemarks returned into our response array
    $responseData['serialNumberRemarks'] = getSerialNumberRemarks($machineName, $pdoConnection);
    echo json_encode($responseData); //echo the response data back to the client
  }
?>
```

Comment: @Anu Hey Anu. Just a little note, I took your PHP code out from the function as it was easier to work with. But I can edit the answer to show you how to work with the function if you need it like that. I know you have other answers to choose from too but if you're still stuck let me know :)

Comment: Hey Sarah, For my case, the above code is somehow not working. I am still figuring out if its an issue from my side or not. By the way I am curious to know also how it work with the function too

Comment: `var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);` it is stuck here with an uncaught error
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ajaxCallback (calReportCreate.php:132)
ajaxCallback @ calReportCreate.php:132`

Comment: It means that there is something wrong with the JSON being returned from the PHP file. This could be something to do with the format of serialNumberRemarks. what does this variable contain?

Comment: The variable contains some string values. Eg: 123AB

Comment: @Anu I added a screenshot to show how you can check the response in the Network tab. Are you using the PHP code from my answer or different code?

Comment: I found one mistake. I didn't declare the $conn as global. I am checking further

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188321/discussion-between-anu-and-sarah).

Comment: Managed to get your code working after included the connection code into `machine_number_processing.php` file. Code as below

`$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "test";


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);`

based on your suggestion. Thanks a lot for helping out

Comment: @Anu thats great! No probs :)

Answer (score 0):

you must use jQuery/Ajax here. If you use php you must submit first the form in order to get the `$_POST` data. This time I think you are looking for the `event handling` of the elements. Let's try:

**ON YOUR HTML** Change your code to this:

```
 <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
  <label>Machine</label><br>
  <select class="combobox form-control col-sm-2" id="machineNumber" 
       name="machineNumber">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select><br>
  <label id="machineSer">Machine Serial Number: 
   </label>
</div>
```

**SAMPLE SCRIPT**

```
     $("#machineNumber").change(function(){
            var id= $("#machineNumber option:selected").text();



           $.ajax({
                url:"call the function to your php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{
                    machinenum:id
                },
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(data){
               $('#machineSer').text("Machine Serial Number: "+data);
         }

      })
    });
```

**YOUR PHP FUNCTION QUERY**

```
<?php
function labelVal(){
    if(isset($_POST['machinenum'])){
        $machineName = $_POST['machinenum'];

        $query = "SELECT machineSerialRemarks FROM machinenames WHERE machineName = 
     '$machineName'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

      echo json_encode($row);
    }
  }
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So `url:"call the function to your php",` means the function should be in a different php file and I need to give the location of that file here? Can I use a php function in the same HTML file by giving php tags?

Comment: Or else you can call the `php file` where the query/returning of data is committing.

Comment: Sorry...i didn't get the `call the function to your php`. What should I exactly put there? My function is in the same file where the html codes are. function name is labelVal()

Comment: You should put the php code in a file of its own. I.e "machine_number_processing.php" and that should be the "url" you enter in the above code

Comment: The above code is not working when I tried. Could be something wrong at my side. Basically when i change the drop down menu, nothing is happening

Comment: @Anu, since you are working on `ajax (backend)` there maybe no error shown on front end side. Try to check on `Browser's Console` by pressing **F12**. Also you can check there under `Network->XHR` tab if you are using **Chrome**. You can just try to remove your php code inside the `labelVal()` function so that you can call the php file itself.

Comment: `Network->XHR` showing no error as well. And showing some coloured graph with a few lines

Comment: Even though the code looks quite logical, but due to some unknown reason, i can't get it work with me.

Answer (score 0):

Should look something like this (untested for obvious reasons).

Note that I changed `name` to `id` to make it more easily accessible. I also changed your request to GET since a) it only gets information from the server without storing anything, per GET contract, and b) because it makes `fetch` a bit easier. The code below watches for when the value of `<select>` changes, and then sends a request to a PHP backend. It can be a separate file like in my example, or you can test to see if a request has `machine` parameter to shunt it to your function. When it prints its value, we come back to JavaScript with that value in the response's body, so we'll extract it using `text` and then finally insert it into the HTML. Note that you can't have it directly using PHP tags, because that happens before the page is loaded, and there's no way to reinterpret it later at clientside - we need to use normal markup, and change the DOM like I showed.

```js
document.querySelector('#machineNumber').addEventListener('change', evt => {
  fetch("http://example.com/get_remarks.php?machineNumber=" + evt.target.value)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => document.querySelector('#machineSer').textContent = text);
})
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-sm-2">
  <label>Machine</label><br>
  <select class="combobox form-control col-sm-2" name="machineNumber" id="machineNumber">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select><br>
  <label id="machineSer">Machine Serial Number: <span id="machineSer"></span></label>
</div>
```